# Permutation vs Combination

Tags: combinatorics

I get wrong a lot identifying if order does matter or doesn't (Combination/Permutation), here are some example questions:

1. a group of girls/boys are being elected into committee

   - committee spots (spot) - order doesn't matter.
   - girls/boys (object) - order does matter(peoples are different).
2. number of order possibilities of the word "YYYABCDEF" where Y can't be next to each other.
   so we order all the rest ABCDEF, then between the letters we can put YYY so:

   - between the letters spots(spot) - order does matter(each placement will give different word).
   - Y letter(object) - order doesnt matter(its the same letter).

In both examples as I know the answer will use "C - Combination".

but in the first example the spot order doesn't matter and the object order does matter.
the second is the opposite.

My question is how do I know which one, the object or the spot to address when choosing Combination/Permutation?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

I am unclear about what you are asking, but understand that although *permutations* and *combinations* are often paired, they are fundamentally different ideas.

A **permutation** is a unique *ordering* of a fixed number of objects. For example, given three objects $A$, $B$, and $C$, let us list all of their permutations:

$$ABC\\
ACB\\
BAC\\
BCA\\
CAB\\
CBA$$

A **combination** is a unique *selection* of any number of objects. For example, given three fruits $\{\text{banana},\text{apple},\text{orange}\}$, let us list all of their combinations if we can only choose two fruits:

$$
\{\text{banana},\text{apple}\}\\
\{\text{banana},\text{orange}\}\\
\{\text{apple},\text{orange}\}
$$

Note that since we think in terms of sets, order does not matter. I.e.,
$$\{\text{banana},\text{apple}\}=\{\text{apple},\text{banana}\}$$